# cx_Oracle returned value as variable

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am running following code -

```
cuidsql = "SELECT CUST_ID FROM XXCUST_HIER_DATA WHERE CUST_NAME = "+"'"+str(cust_name)+"' AND END_DATE IS NULL"

cursor.execute(cuidsql)
custIdVal = cursor.var(int)
print(custIdVal)
```

I am expecting output as number which is customer ID.
But the output I am getting is -
<cx_Oracle.Var of type DB_TYPE_NUMBER with value None>

When I run the same SQL for a customer I am getting output as 2339.
How can I get this and assign this value to custIdVal?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple query, you would use a fetch method or iterator to get rows.

Importantly you *must* use bind variables instead of `"+"'"+str(cust_name)+"'`. Bind variables help performance, scalability, and security.

Start with the example [bind_insert.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/bind_insert.py):

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = 'select * from SampleQueryTab where id = :bvid'

print("Query results with id = 4")
for row in cursor.execute(sql, bvid = 4):
    print(row)
print()

print("Query results with id = 1")
for row in cursor.execute(sql, bvid = 1):
    print(row)
print()
```

or look at [query.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/query.py):

```
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

I recommend reviewing the [doc](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), the [tutorial](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-Scripting-for-the-Future.html) and all the [examples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/main/samples).